# Image Iteration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a  better way to iterate the following images?

```
NSArray *imageNames = @[@"MyImage-0.png", @"MyImage-1.png", @"MyImage-2.png",@"MyImage-3.png",@"MyImage-4.png", @"MyImage-5.png", @"MyImage-6.png", @"MyImage-7.png"];

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    mImageView.animationImages = images;
    mImageView.animationDuration = 1.5;

    [self.view mImageView];
    [mImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: `NSArray *imageNames` is defined manually? `NSMutableArray *images = [imageNames mutableCopy]` will do the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSInteger imagesCount = 7;    
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i <= imagesCount; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyImage-%d", i]]];
    }

    mImageView.animationImages = images;
    mImageView.animationDuration = 1.5;

    [self.view mImageView];
    [mImageView startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumeration

```
for(NSString *imageStr in imageNames)
{
   [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageStr]];
}
```

This takes less time to iterate.

Hope it helps you...!

Answer (score 0):

The better way will be not using for loop. Try this code

```
+(NSArray*)getSortedArray:(NSMutableArray*)arrayToSort
{
   return [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
}
```

Hope this class method will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use some handy library, like [this one](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage). Look, it even supports GIF!

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://raphaelschaad.com/static/nyan.gif";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
FLAnimatedImage *image = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:data];
FLAnimatedImageView *imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animatedImage = image;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```